# Android listview adapter with buttons in getView that change the layout

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a listview with a few buttons that I want to disclose more information. I have an xml file for the layout with several nested LinearLayouts. When the "Comments" button is pressed I want the appropriate layout to appear and then disappear. Inside of the model object I keep track of whether or not the view is disclosed.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final CarmenGrade grade = (CarmenGrade) getItem(position);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.carmen_grade_item, null);
    commentsLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentsLayout);
    commentsButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentsButton);

    commentsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (grade.isShowingComments() == true) {
                    commentsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    grade.setShowingComments(false);
                    /* other similar layout parts cut */
                } else {
                    commentsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    grade.setShowingComments(true);
                    /* other similar layout parts cut */
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

On Android 4.x it works on the first press and the proper layout becomes visible. Pressing the button again doesn't appear to work consistently. Every once in a while it'll disappear.

On Android 5.0 I get a lot of warnings although it appears to work most of the time:

```
W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{2d2581cb V.ED.... ......ID 0,57-231,114 #7f0a0086 app:id/weightedValueTextView} during layout: running second layout pass
```

So my question is - how can I use items within the list to change the layout within getView so that it works consistently and doesn't throw errors? Am I missing a different, super obvious pattern?

**EDIT**
Sorry, forgot to put in the place where I initialized the comments layout. It's definitely there.

Comment: where you initializing the comments layout ?

Comment: `commentsLayout` is initialized?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that part. The layout has been initialized and is non-null.

Comment: is that a local variable of the function or is it a global variable ?

Comment: Try make `commentsLayout` and `commentsButton` as local variables in method `getView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adapter, getView() function is called many times. So when you go to find some view of `carmen_grade_item` inside listener it will return you object which was initiated in last (Means of it may point to same object of other row from listview).

So to overcome this problem:

If you want to use it inside  your adapter class : Maintain a viewHolder of specific row into array. or find specific layout like `clickedView.getParent().findViewById(R.id.someLayout)`; and then perform your action.

So your listener would look like this

```
    commentsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) ((MainParent which contains child)
v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.commentsLayout);

                        if(layout.isShown()){
                            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else{
                            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }


                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: This variation still yields the warnings on 5.0 and now when I hit the button the second time to make the view disappear it crashes saying that the layout is null. It's almost as if it isn't updating the view properly.

Comment: Have you enabled fastScroll to listview in your XML or runtime. Please disable or set false and check your code.

Comment: why you are calling the method                     notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: It is used to refresh observers of view. But you're right here @cfihelp only changes visibility of layout not any data so there is no need to call that.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use boolean variable do it as below.

```
 if (commentsLayout.isShown()) {
       commentsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 } else {
        commentsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```